# How to split a single file with 10 commits into 10 files with single commit?

Tags: git, split, git-commit

I have a file with multiple commits, I want to split this file into multiple files with single commit each.

**For example** :
`A.cpp` has git history of :
`commit message 1`. Egg dropping problem
`commit message 2`. Invert a binary tree

I want to have two files named as 
 
1. `Egg dropping Problem.cpp` **which contains data of `commit 1` only.**
2. `Invert a binary tree.cpp` **which contains data of `commit 2` only.**

Comment: There isn't much you can do here in the way of breaking it into separate commits, assuming all 10 changes came in as one commit.

Comment: No, we have 10 different commits of single file, each commit represents a single logical problem which has no relation with previous commit. Now, I want to have different files for each logical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `git format-patch`

> `format-patch` creates one patch file for **each commit** you specify.

```
# x is the number of commits you need
# git format-patch HEAD~X (or the next one:)
`git format-patch ~<first-sha1>`
```

Comment: Thanks! but now I have 10 patch files, how do I make them 10 `cpp` files ?
do I need to apply each patch and then rename the file and repeat the process?

Comment: exactly, apply the series of patches on top of your base code